# Android recorded video play on samsung device but blur on Htc device

Tags: android, video-recording

I created video on android that properties is :

```
                    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);

        mRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);

        mRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(24);
        mRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(8000);

        mRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);




        mRecorder.setMaxDuration((int) (maxDuration));

        mRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mOutputFileName);
        mRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
```

but this video create and play both on samsung device properly but htc device shows blur video.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT` so every smartphone will choose its default video codec to record it (and you don't know which one it will be. It's likely HTCs and Samsungs default codecs are different). Try to set `MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264` instead.

Comment: I have tried this, but by using MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264, the video recorded was blur and didn't display properly.